# Draw content to canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html2canvas

How is it possible to draw the below on to canvas without using a plugin like html2canvas?

[**jsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/f6bx6ktb/2/)

```
<div id="test">
    asadasd <br />
    fsdf<br />
    sdfsd<br />
    sdfsdfsdf<br />
</div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

js:

```
function myCanvas() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.getElementById("test");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
}
```

Comment: I found a tutorial: http://eloquentjavascript.net/16_canvas.html

Comment: Will the div only contain text, or will there be other elements?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send a HTML as variable to the canvas object. It's illegal. It would be than easy to actually *print-screen* someone's changes to the page and send that image to the server. Without doing it *dynamically* (HTML>var) you can instead use `foreignObject` <sup>[*Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)</sup>.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200" height="200">' +
    '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
    '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" id="test" style="font-size:16px; background:gold;">'+
    'asadasd <br />' +
    'fsdf<br />' +
    'sdfsd<br />' +
    'sdfsdfsdf<br />' +
    '</div>' +
    '</foreignObject>' +
    '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;

var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
};

img.src = url;
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="150" height="150" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;"></canvas>
```

Comment: thanks. How do I use < foreignobject >? Do I need to wrap it around each text? Appreciate if you could show me a example using my above text Fiddle.

Comment: @Beki added an example. I know you'll now try to get that HTML as a `var c = "<div>...."` Don't. You cannot. :)

Comment: Why isn't the text sowing on the canvas?

Comment: @Beki what browser do you use? (Shows for me in Chrome)

Comment: I generally use chrome but in this case I'm using IE 11

Comment: So basically you're saying, if I need to create a canvas with a bunch of text drawn in to it, using a plugin like `html2canvas` is the way to go?

Comment: @Beki exactly, that's why they're developing that tool for years now :) So that we don't have to reinvent the hot water :)

Comment: Just tossing in my experience with html2canvas: It works well for simple html+css combinations but it gets increasingly inaccurate especially as the css gets fancier. Your simple design should work fine. Also, as you noticed...`foreignObject` is not supported in Internet Explorer as a way to scrape a Div.

Comment: @markE IE was never good at web... :) Yes, I investigated further, I've used foreignobject but just for a specific Chrome environment. Yes, you cannot use fancy JS, CSS3 stuff with HTML2CANVAS. People mostly use it to convert tabular data for user preview. Not sure what you're after but there are ways to setup a ghost browser and let it make actual screenshots of the desired page. It's extremely hard to setup it right in linux, but I'm not sure what's your project anyway ;)